# ¿Porque me sale el error de Could not load type 'Administrators.Global'.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Quiero correr mi aplicación pero no puedo ya que me marca el siguiente error:

> Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" 
>   Inherits="Administrators.Global" Language="C#" %>

con el siguiente texto:

> An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Ya lo **debuguee** y lo limpie e inclusive abrir y cerre el proyecto en visual studio.

Comment: has verificado que si en tu proyecto tienes la carpeta con nombre App_Code

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621069/global-asax-parse-error-after-minor-change-and-revert-to-previous-version